# how is PHP distorting my HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've been running into some problems that seem to arise from making my questionnaire a .PHP file rather than an .HTML.  The reason I had to do this is because I'm using a PHP script for working with an SQL database and I had to include them into the Questionnaire, which won't work as an HTML.

In the HTML version everything runs perfectly the way I coded it. When I saved it as a .php file my javascript stopped working properly and I tried linking the javascript at the bottom of the body tag instead of the head and that still didn't help.

After a lot of going back and forth trying to see what's different I decided to save the .php file as an html just for grins and giggles to see if I still got the same problems.  Oddly enough, it runs just as smooth as the other HTML file.

here's links to all 3 versions so you can see what I mean.

[HTML v1](http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Corp_ID_&_Branding_Questionnaire.html)

[PHP](http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Corp_ID_&_Branding_Questionnaire.php)

[HTML v2](http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Corp_ID_&_Branding_Questionnaire_2.html)

In the JS Console I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

which referred me to line 163 of my .js file which is referencing the "next" button of the first page of the Questionnaire (not intro page that loads up but the next page where you actually input data).

The way I have the Questionnaire structured in the .PHP file is

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors','on'); ?><?php include('extlib/vdaemon/vdaemon.php'); ?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 //links to files etc.//
</head>
<header>
</header>
<body>
    <form action="core/process.php" method="post" id="CorpID" runat="vdaemon">

    <input type="hidden" name="formID" value="Questionnaire" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://optiqvision.x10host.com/Corp_ID_&_Branding_Questionnaire.html" />

    //all form inputs//
    
    </form>
    <?php VDEnd(); ?>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

The entire Questionnaire has well over 100 individual inputs so I didn't want to put all of them in this snippet.  I just wanted to show the over all structure, plus I figured you could get more details in the browser from clicking on them and looking at the debugger to see more of what's going on.  Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong with the PHP?  I really don't understand why it's messing up the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Looks like the real problem is that the DOM is broken.  In your PHP file, you have a self-closed textarea tag.  textarea tags need a closing tag.

```
<!-- you have this, it's not syntactically correct  -->
<textarea id="my_comp" class="tex_inp01" style="width:88%; height:100px; font-size:14pt;" />
<!-- the following is correct -->
<textarea id="my_comp" class="tex_inp01" style="width:88%; height:100px; font-size:14pt;"></textarea>
```

Put Corp_ID_&_Branding_Questionnaire.js right before the body tag and it will work.  The reason the PHP file is throwing a javascript error is because the node "p1_next" doesn't exist at runtime since your JS is in the head tag.

The reason it's working in the HTML file is mainly thanks to luck.  The static HTML is loading fast enough that the DOM is ready by the time your JS code is running.  As a thumb of rule, generally include all your JS right before the body tag.  There are of course some exceptions.

If you really need to include your script in the head, you can wait until the DOM is ready by wrapping all your code with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    // your JS code here
});
```

Last, if you're going to be using jQuery as a library, then it is recommended to use jQuery syntax instead of native JS.  Just make sure to include the jQuery JS before your code.

```
var p1a = document.getElementById("p1_next");
// becomes:
var p1a = $('#p1_next'); // jQuery node by CSS selector
```

Before the end of the body tag like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ..your code ..
  </head>
  <body>
    ..your code ..
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Files/Javascript/Corp_ID_&_Branding_Questionnaire.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: before the end of the body tag.  Ok I just looked at your code and you aren't even closing your body and html tags.  I've edited my answer to include a snippet at the bottom.  Also, the <header> tag cannot go in the <head> tag.  It should be in the <body> tag.  I suggest you run your HTML code through an HTML validator.

Comment: @MrLister thx!  I didn't know I had to escape these.  I edited my answer and found your comment after.

Comment: hmm.. idk how I deleted the closing tags off on the first sample.  but they're on the php and 2nd html.  Also where did you see the header inside of the head tag?  I'm lost on that one.   I just put the .js file at the bottom of the body tag like you suggested, as I also tried once before, and I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: ok I just noticed in the sample I gave up top I didn't close them off, was typing too fast rushing to get answers lol.

Comment: Ok I had a second look and it looks like the problem is the textarea tag on line 353 of the rendered PHP file.  It needs a closing tag </textarea> as textarea don't self close with />.  Here's what's being rendered: As for the header tag, sorry it's not in the head tag, but in between your head and body tag.  It need to be inside the body tag.  Same as your footer tag.

Comment: yeah I caught the textarea tag in an html validator.  I made the adjustments and it's still doing the same exact thing except now I see two buttons at the top, which I'm guessing is page 2's buttons because there's only 1 on page 1 which isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

In your html the code for the textarea is like this:

```
<textarea id="my_comp" class="tex_inp01" style="width:88%; height:100px; font-size:14pt;"></textarea>
```

In your php the

The textarea closing tag is misplaced; coming after a lot of div's including the element with the id=p1_next. SO the divs just become part of the textarea value instead of being part of the HTML page